# How to issue LLC membership units for each founder to own 1/3 of the company?

Tags: business, corporate-law

There are three LLC founders that each own 1/3 of the company. In the LLC operating agreement, we would would like to have 100 membership units total to represent 100% ownership of the company.

- How do I reflect this on the membership units?
- Do I issue fractional shares?
- Do I scrap the 100 total units?

Comment: ...As Dale M said: scrap the 100 units.  You could go for 300?

Comment: Why do you want 100 units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to issue a number of units divisible by 3, like ... 3.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess there's no reason to peg the units at 100. I'll go with 300 total units.